# How to get first N rows from every category in Django

Tags: python, django

I have following models, with many to many table, for which I would like to get first 20 news from every category in single response.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=45)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

class News(models.Model):
    source_code = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    scraped_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', through='NewsCategory')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'news'
        verbose_name_plural = 'News'


class NewsCategory(models.Model):
    news_id = models.ForeignKey(News, db_column='news_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_code = models.ForeignKey(Category, db_column='category_code', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'news_category'
        unique_together = (('news_id', 'category_code'),)
        verbose_name_plural = 'NewsCategory'
```

My view class looks like this, and here I would like to add some logic to return 20 rows for each category, for example if I have 5 categories it should return 100 news in single request.

```
class NewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']    
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = News.objects.all().order_by('-published_at')
        sources = self.request.query_params.getlist('sources')

        if len(sources) > 0:
            queryset = queryset.filter(source_code__in=sources)

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to use a window function. Django has support for them but I don't think they allow filtering on the output of them. I think this is further complicated by the m2m field. Given it's not too complex and doesn't seem to involve user input, you might just want to use a raw query.

Here's what it might look like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.code ORDER BY n.published_at DESC) AS row_num
  FROM appname_news n
    JOIN appname_newscategory nc
      ON n.id = c.news_id
    JOIN appname_category c
      ON nc.category_code = c.code
) sub
WHERE
  row_num <= 20
```

And see here for Django's guide on how to actually implement this in a view:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Adding the Django ticket tracking adding this ability via queryset (5 years old..): https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333